# spTransform() in R warnings with PROJ

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal, proj

I'm in R v 4.0.4 - sp v 1.4-5, and rgdal 1.5-23.  I'm loading a shapefile using the rgdal package and then trying to simply apply spTransform() but I'm getting a ridiculous set of warnings that I can't get rid of. Anyone have any insight on this?

```
options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none")
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

## Shapefile has a projection of WGS84
X <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="myshapefile.shp")
UTM30 <- sf::st_crs(32630)$proj4string

transf <- spTransform(X,UTM30)

############################################################
### This warning gets repeated tens to hundreds of times ###

proj_as_proj_string: C:\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.1\proj\proj.db lacks DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation.
proj_as_wkt: C:\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.1\proj\proj.db lacks DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation.
proj_create: C:\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.1\proj\proj.db lacks DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation.
```

Anyone come across this yet and managed to squash it?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Found this explanation from [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html):

The 'GDAL' and 'PROJ' libraries are external to the package, and, when installing the package from source, must be correctly installed first; it is important that 'GDAL' < 3 be matched with 'PROJ' < 6. From 'rgdal' 1.5-8, installed with to 'GDAL' >=3, 'PROJ' >=6 and 'sp' >= 1.4, coordinate reference systems use 'WKT2_2019' strings, not 'PROJ' strings.